# How can I open and close a popup menu when I click on a window in win32 api?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, popupmenu

I made a little window with the win32 api and want to open a popup menu when I click on the window. When I click on it again I want to close the menu if it's still open.

I open the menu on **WM_LBUTTONUP**, because I want to drag the window on **WM_LBUTTONDOWN**.

I know when the menu appears or disappears by **WM_ENTERMENULOOP** and **WM_EXITMENULOOP**.

I know how to close the menu programmatically, but unfortunately I don't know how to decide whether the menu is open or closed on **WM_LBUTTONUP**. The problem is that the menu gets automatically closed on **WM_LBUTTONDOWN** and that's why I can't save the current state of the menu.

It would be great if someone has a hint how to solve this problem.

**Additional information:**

- the whole window is a borderless client-area with a bitmap painted on it

  ```
  hWnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"MyWindow", 0, WS_POPUP, wndPosX, wndPosY, m_WndWidth, m_WndHeight, 0, 0, m_hInst, 0);
  ```
- the bitmap gets loaded on **WM_CREATE** in the WindowProcedure of the window and is painted on **WM_PAINT**

  ```
  m_hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(NULL, "MyBitmap.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, m_WndWidth, m_WndHeight, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  ```
- the window isn't draggable by default, because I don't have a non-client area, that's why I move the window manually on **WM_MOUSEMOVE** according to the current cursor position
- On **WM_LBUTTONUP** I create the popup menu on top of the window

  ```
  HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
  InsertMenuW(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_ITEM_A, L"ItemA");
  SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
  RECT wndRect;
  GetWindowRect(hWnd, &wndRect);
  TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, wndRect.left, wndRect.top, 0, hWnd, NULL);
  ```

Comment: If you want to change how menus work your best bet is to install a `WH_MSGFILTER` hook before you display it. Then you can monitor and modify the messages it receives (e.g. change `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to `WM_NULL` if you want it to ignore a mouse click).

Comment: Does dragging the window affect the menu? You can follow Jonathan's way to avoid mouse click(`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`). Generally, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` occurs in the action with a mouse.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm very new to the win api. How can I install the hook? And how can I modify the messages it receives?

Comment: Maybe there is an alternative way to do that. Can I prevent the popup menu to close itself by clicking somewhere? Then I can handle it by myself.

Comment: The little window belong to a main window? Or is it a separate window? Maybe you can add some code to illustrate your problem

Comment: Some information is needed. Is the window borderless? Do you mean using `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to click on the title bar to drag the window? For the use of hooks, you can refer to [using hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks)

Comment: I just added some more information and code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using WindowsHooks for mouse event
You have to catch mouse down event inside the window client area and skip the next mouse up event

in global scope

```
static HHOOK hMouseHook = 0;
static HWND hMainWindow = 0;
static int nSkipClick = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(_In_ int    nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* p = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (WindowFromPoint(p->pt) == hMainWindow) {
            POINT pt = p->pt;
            ScreenToClient(hMainWindow, &pt);
            RECT rct;
            GetClientRect(hMainWindow, &rct);
            if (PtInRect(&rct, pt))nSkipClick = 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

in WndProc

```
case WM_LBUTTONUP: 
    if (nSkipClick == 0) { // menu not shown before
        hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, &MouseProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
        hMainWindow = hWnd;
        HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
        InsertMenuW(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, ID_ITEM_A, L"ItemA");
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        RECT wndRect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &wndRect);
        TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, wndRect.left, wndRect.top, 0, hWnd, NULL);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hMouseHook);
        hMouseHook = 0;
    }
    else {
        nSkipClick = 0;
    }
break;
```

I hope this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem here is that the condition in_menu == 0 is always true, because the menu gets closed before WM_LBUTTONDOWN is received when I click on the window. In this case it opens all the time. In general the menu closes when I click somewhere, it doesn't matter if I click on my window or somewhere else.

Comment: I checked your edit. Now the window opens the menu if i click on the window and closes it when I click on the window again. That's fine. If I click on the window and open the menu and then click somewhere else, the menu closes and I cannot open it again by clicking on the window. If I click another time, then it will open again. Maybe there is a way to register if the menu gets closed by clicking on the window or by something else. I'm really stuck with this problem, but i think there is a solution to it. I want to avoid installing a hook or something like that.

Comment: @MarBot Can you share the reasons for not using hooks?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using hooks, but I assume there's no other possibility. Do I need to include DLLs for that?